# MSQL Query to list Simple Products for missing images

Tags: mysql, query

Line 3 is apparently incorrectly written. Can a MySql expert offer fixed query? Thanks!

```
SELECT  `rscno` 
FROM  `catalog_product_entity` WHERE `type_id` = 'simple' 
AS a INNER JOIN  `eav_attribute` AS `attribute` ON `attribute.attribute_code` =  'image'
AND `attribute.frontend_input` =  'media_image'
LEFT JOIN  `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS b ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id
AND b.attribute_id = attribute.attribute_id
WHERE b.value =  ''
OR b.value IS NULL 
OR b.value =  'no_selection'
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

**#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AS a INNER JOIN `eav_attribute` AS `attribute` ON `attribute.attribute_code` = ' at line 3**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what your query does, but

```
SELECT  `sku` 
FROM  `catalog_product_entity` AS a 
INNER JOIN  `eav_attribute` AS `attribute` ON `attribute`.attribute_code =  'image'
AND `attribute`.frontend_input =  'media_image'
LEFT JOIN  `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS b ON a.entity_id = b.entity_id
AND b.attribute_id = attribute.attribute_id
WHERE `type_id` = 'simple' AND (b.value =  ''
OR b.value IS NULL 
OR b.value =  'no_selection')
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

Should fix the problem.

`AS a` needs to be after a `FROM` table or after a `JOIN`

Comment: Fabian I'm getting the same response error from your query code. I want to print out all the"rscno" product numbers from the table "catalog_product_entity", which are exclusively the ones that are of the "type_id" which equals "simple", that do not have an "media_image". This is a Magento query. Thank you for your previous answer!

Comment: Lots of missed set ` and a WHERE on the wrong position. This query works for me. NOW :-)